Most Keyboard Keys Stopped Working on E15 Laptop
Recently, almost all of my Keys stopped working on my e15 thinkpad, and I am not quite sure how to diagnose if this is a hardware issue or not. I don't remember how it started. My usual Keyboard Layout is Neoqwertz, but the issue persists if I change the Keyboard layout with setxkbmap us for example. Any ideas for next steps to diagnose this? Here are the things I tried so far:
Observations/Things I tried:

All Keys except for F1, F2 and the Fn key stopped working (those three Keys still send events that are registered when I run sudo showkey -s.
When I run sudo showkey -s there are a bunch of 0x29 Key events even though I am not pressing any keys.
The indication light on my F1 key is glowing, which I think means the mic is muted. This indication light is usually off. Meanwhile, the Indication light on the Esc/Fnlock key is off, which is usually on.
Using an external Keyboard works.
I put off the cap from the Ctrl key to inspect it, but I cannot see anything that is off (It seems the 0x29 events are the ctrl key, because when I reloaded my keyboard settings it also started affecting the external keyboard, and just pressing l in firefox focused the url bar and other behavior indicating the ctrl key being pressed).
The Keyboard is also not working in the bios
rebooting does not change things
running sudo apt-get --reinstall install xserver-xorg-input-libinput didn't change things
F1 is outputting very weird characters when I run sudo showkey -s:

1-^[[1;5H^[[5;5~^[[3;5~0xe0 0x47 0xe0 0x49 0xe0 0x53 0xe0 0x52 0x43 0x0c 0x42 0x0d 
^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 
^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 
^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 
^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 
^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 
^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~^[[3;5~0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x1d 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 0x29 ```


Is one of the keys stuck? Do you see the same behavior from a LiveCD/LiveUSB?
